# Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments,....) how can it be done?

Tags: javascript

i am trying to implement different array methods on arguments only for experiment purpose.I was able to use slice and join methods.But i can't figure out how can i add an extra element in arguments list using unshift method.it is giving an unexpected result .it is giving the value 3 ,which i don't know from where it is comming.how it can be done?

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function init(){

        console.log(arguments);
        console.log(arguments.length);
        console.log(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,'__'));
        console.log(Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments));
      }
      init(1,2,3);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

result:

```
Arguments { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 2 more… } 
3 
"1__2__3" 
3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift):

> > Returns
> >     The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

It's returning `3` because `arguments.length` is 3 when you call it and you're not passing any new elements to the method.

You should be able to just call:

```
console.log(Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, "a", "b", "c")));
console.log(arguments);
```

And see:

```
6
Arguments { 0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 3, 2 more… }
```

Comment: And since no new elements are added, the length stays the same.

Comment: thanks a lot!! but i wonder why console.log(Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, "a", "b", "c"))); prints out the length of new arguments list.i mean why it is showing the length of new arguments array??why i have to call console.log(arguments) again??

Comment: @user3138436 That's simply the way it was defined 15 years ago. I'm sure the standards writers had their reasons for it at the time, but I would not know what they are. It would be somewhat misleading for `unshift()` to return the modified array, since it might lead people to forget that it actually mutates the provided array.

Comment: Maybe the answer is obvious, but why are we calling these methods by using `Array.prototype` instead of just doing `arguments.unshift(...)`?

Comment: @user3138436: `.push` behaves the same way.

Comment: @nzifnab: Because `arguments` is not an array, it's an **array-like** object. `arguments.unshift` simply does not exist.

Comment: @FelixKling huh.  Learn something new everyday.  Thanks :P

Answer (score 1):

That's because `unshift` returns the number of elements in the modified array, but modifies the array in-place:

```
array = [1,2,3]
// [1, 2, 3]
array.unshift(7)
// 4
array
// [7, 1, 2, 3]
```